# is_dir doesn't work with for loop

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to loop through images and thumbnails from a folder and insert them into a database.
I want to use is_dir to filter out directories.

I have:

```
$images = scandir('./images/all_comics/');
$thumbs = scandir('./images/thumbnails/');

for($x=0; $x<count($images); $x++) 
   {
    if(!is_dir($images[$x]))
       {
        //This shows all images WITHOUT directories
        echo $images[$x]; 

        //This is STILL adding images AND directories to database
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO images (imgpath, thumbpath) VALUES ('$images[$x]', '$thumbs[$x]')");
       }
   }
```

I have a check in there directly after !is_dir, **echo $images[$x]** ,which echos out all images without the directories, as desired.

But when I check the insert in the database, I see that the directories have been added as records. Why is this?

Thank you!

Comment: Use `glob` - `$images = glob('./images/all_comics/*.jpg');`, changing format accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Deleting old answer, as the issue was a typo)

`scandir` returns a list of files in a given directory. When you use `is_dir`, it's looking in the current directory for those files. I think what you need to do is:

```
if(!is_dir("./images/all_comics/" . $images[$x])) {
....
```

Comment: Okay, that was a little mistake I made in typing. It's still doing the same thing even after the fix.

Comment: So the echo statement is not printing anything for directories, but still adding them?

Answer (score 2):

Your `echo` is executed inside `if`, but query does not:

```
for($x=0; $x<count($images); $x++) 
{
       if(!is_dir($images[$x]))
       {
        echo $images[$x]; //This shows all images WITHOUT directories
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO images (imgpath, thumbpath) VALUES ('$images[$x]', '$thumbs[$x]')");
       }
}
```

Also, get rid of `mysql_*` for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), and consider [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) as a way to browse for files excluding directories.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use glob

```
$files = glob('./images/all_comics/*');
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if (!is_dir($file)) {
            //Do Insert
        }
    }
```